# setUpTestData integrity error; database does not refresh

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django unit testing and trying to understand how to instantiate fixtures for a class, that are then removed from the database once the tests in the class are finished.

My understanding is its best to use [setUpTestData](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) for this. However, when set up the same fixtures in two different classes, I get a `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` error:

```
class TestClass1(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.i1 = Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 1')
        cls.i2 = Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 2')
        cls.i3 = Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 3')

    def test_1A(self):
       // etc

class TestClass2(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.i1 = Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 1')
        cls.i2 = Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 2')
        cls.i3 = Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 3')

    def test_2A(self):
       // etc
```

Produces:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myapp_issuer_pkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) already exists.

Why doesn't the database "reset" after each TestCase class is complete? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that django rolls back your changes, but as your id is "Primary key" and "auto increment" by default, and django sets up the database only once, then your id index of increment doesn't turn back, but the data will be deleted after the implementation of the tests in Class.

So if you have 2 classes of test like:

```
class TestClass1(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 1')
        Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 2')
        Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 3')

    def test_1(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)


class TestClass2(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        Issuer.objects.create(issuer_name='Issuer 1')
    

    def test_1(self):
        print(Channel.objects.last().id)
        self.assertEqual(Channel.objects.all().count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(Channel.objects.last().id, 4)
```

and these are the only tests of your django project(!), then these 2 test will pass.

In your problem, it seems you have relied on not existing of id 6, but having 3 objects on your database present, does not mean that the id of the last one is 3 and it depends on the order of tests running.

I hope you get the idea of how setUpTestData works and let me know if there is any ambiguity or if it didn't answered you well.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't follow your explanation. If django removes the objects from the database, then why is the primary key still causing a duplicate error? How do I fix this?

Comment: @alias51 It depends how you create objects of that class. You should check where this exception is raising and how you are creating objects and from this data I can't understand how it raised. For example if I want to create an object in second TestCase class and give it an id = 1 to construct it, I can face and error. Are you sure you only create object in SetUpTestData?